# Porta não encontrada - Arduino IDE no Linux Mint

Tags: linux, arduino, mint

Recentemente comecei a usar Arduino e passei por um processo de migração(windows para linux mint), Me deparei com um erro frequênte onde o arduino não era reconhecido, sua porta era inacessível, impedindo o meu upload.

Abaixo segue imagem com o erro que descrevi, gostaria de ajuda para interpretar esta saída e resolver o problema.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá! Após pesquisar um pouco mais, encontrei uma solução que cai bem para situações onde ocorreram vários erros durante a instalação e a IDE não foi instalada completamente, ou, como aconteceu comigo, mal funcionamento da IDE.

**Instalação/Reinstalação**

**1** - Visite o [site da Arduino IDE](https://www.arduino.cc/en/main/software) e faça o download do pacote da IDE referênte a arquitetura do seu sistema, os links para download se encontram em um quadro como este abaixo:

[image: Exemplo de quadro dos downloads no site da IDE.]

**2** - Identifique o caminho onde foi salvo o arquivo e navegue até lá.
    **PS:** O arquivo terá um nome semelhante a este: *`arduino-1.8.12-linux64.tar.xz`*

**3** - Extraia o arquivo usando o menu de contexto(Botão direito no arquivo e clique em extrair) ou abra o terminal (geralmente **Ctrl + T ou Ctrl + Alt + T**) e navegue até o diretório. Você também pode abrir  o terminal já no diretório do arquivo clicando dentro dele (diretório) com o botão direito do mouse e escolher a opção 'Abrir terminal'. Em seguida digite o comando:

```
tar -xvf arduino-1.8.12-linux64.tar.xz
```

**4** - Com o terminal aberto no mesmo diretório, delete o arquivo compactado com o comando:

```
sudo rm -r arduino-1.8.12-linux64.tar.xz
```

**5** - Mova o arquivo extraido para o Diretório `/opt` com o comando:

```
sudo mv arduino-1.8.12 /opt
```

**6** - Mude (o terminal) para o diretório da pasta do *arduino* dentro do diretório `/opt`com o comando:

```
cd /opt/arduino-1.8.12
```

**7** - Use o seguinte comando para abrir e editar o script de nome `install.sh`:

```
sudo nano install.sh
```

**8** - Procure dentro do script a linha:

```
RESOURCE_NAME=cc.arduino.arduinoide
```

e retire o `cc.`, ficará assim:

```
RESOURCE_NAME=arduino-arduinoide
```

Para salvar use o atalho **Ctrl + X** e selecione a tecla Y(yes) para salvar as alterações.

**9** - Agora torne o script executável com o comando:

```
sudo chmod +x install.sh
```

e execute:

```
./install.sh
```

Agora os erros estão corrigidos e a IDE funcionará como esperado.

> Este tutórial é uma adaptação de outro encontrado em um fórum americano, Para ver o conteúdo original [Clique Aqui](https://www.instructables.com/id/Install-Arduino-IDE-182-on-Linux/).